# Error C2872 during Qt 5.5 compilation using msvc 2010

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, ambiguity

I'm trying to compile Qt 5.5 with msvc 2010 compiler but with no luck.
My system meets all of the requirments found on the [Qt for Windows - Requirements](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/windows-requirements.html) page and I've tried different configurations, but everyone of them fails.

After every failed compilation I run

```
nmake clean
```

just to make sure there are no problem with upcoming compilation.

My actual configuration is as follow:

```
configure -release -opensource -confirm-license
```

-platform win32-msvc2010

Before posting here I searched on Google but with no luck!

The problem I'm facing is this one :

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility   versione 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tutti i diritti riservati.

        cl -c -Yc -Fp.pch\release\Qt5Versit_pch.pch -Fo.pch\release\Qt5Versit_pch.obj -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -arch:SSE2 -O2 -MD -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_BUILD_VERSIT_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CONTACTS_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -I. -IC:\Qt\qt5\qtbase\include -IC:\Qt\qt5\qtbase\include\QtVersit -IC:\Qt\qt5\qtbase\include\QtVersit\0.0.0 -IC:\Qt\qt5\qtbase\include\QtVersit\0.0.0\QtVersit -Itmp -IC:\Qt\qt5\qtbase\include\QtContacts -IC:\Qt\qt5\qtbase\include\QtCore -I.moc\release -IC:\Qt\qt5\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010 -TP C:\Qt\qt5\qtbase\include\QtVersit\QtVersitDepends
QtVersitDepends
        C:\Qt\qt5\qtbase\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_BUILD_VERSIT_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CONTACTS_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -D_MSC_VER=1600 -D_WIN32 -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/win32-msvc2010 -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtpim/src/versit -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtVersit -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtVersit/0.0.0 -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtVersit/0.0.0/QtVersit -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtpim/src/versit/tmp -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtContacts -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtCore qversitreader.h -o .moc\release\moc_qversitreader.cpp
        C:\Qt\qt5\qtbase\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_BUILD_VERSIT_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CONTACTS_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -D_MSC_VER=1600 -D_WIN32 -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/win32-msvc2010 -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtpim/src/versit -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtVersit -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtVersit/0.0.0 -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtVersit/0.0.0/QtVersit -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtpim/src/versit/tmp -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtContacts -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtCore qversitreader_p.h -o .moc\release\moc_qversitreader_p.cpp
        C:\Qt\qt5\qtbase\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_BUILD_VERSIT_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CONTACTS_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -D_MSC_VER=1600 -D_WIN32 -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/win32-msvc2010 -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtpim/src/versit -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtVersit -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtVersit/0.0.0 -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtVersit/0.0.0/QtVersit -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtpim/src/versit/tmp -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtContacts -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtCore qversitwriter.h -o .moc\release\moc_qversitwriter.cpp
        C:\Qt\qt5\qtbase\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_BUILD_VERSIT_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CONTACTS_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -D_MSC_VER=1600 -D_WIN32 -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/win32-msvc2010 -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtpim/src/versit -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtVersit -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtVersit/0.0.0 -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtVersit/0.0.0/QtVersit -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtpim/src/versit/tmp -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtContacts -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtCore qversitwriter_p.h -o .moc\release\moc_qversitwriter_p.cpp
        C:\Qt\qt5\qtbase\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_BUILD_VERSIT_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CONTACTS_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -D_MSC_VER=1600 -D_WIN32 -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/win32-msvc2010 -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtpim/src/versit -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtVersit -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtVersit/0.0.0 -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtVersit/0.0.0/QtVersit -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtpim/src/versit/tmp -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtContacts -IC:/Qt/qt5/qtbase/include/QtCore qversitcontacthandler.h -o .moc\release\moc_qversitcontacthandler.cpp
        rc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_BUILD_VERSIT_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CONTACTS_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -fo .obj\release\Qt5Versit_resource.res Qt5Versit_resource.rc
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.1.7600.16385
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl -c -FIQtVersitDepends -YuQtVersitDepends -Fp.pch\release\Qt5Versit_pch.pch -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -arch:SSE2 -O2 -MD -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_BUILD_VERSIT_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CONTACTS_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -I. -IC:\Qt\qt5\qtbase\include -IC:\Qt\qt5\qtbase\include\QtVersit -IC:\Qt\qt5\qtbase\include\QtVersit\0.0.0 -IC:\Qt\qt5\qtbase\include\QtVersit\0.0.0\QtVersit -Itmp -IC:\Qt\qt5\qtbase\include\QtContacts -IC:\Qt\qt5\qtbase\include\QtCore -I.moc\release -IC:\Qt\qt5\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010 -Fo.obj\release\ @C:\Users\Claud\AppData\Local\Temp\nmDE8D.tmp
qversitdocument.cpp
qversitdocument_p.cpp
qversitdocumentwriter_p.cpp
qversitproperty.cpp
qversitreader.cpp
qversitreader_p.cpp
qversitwriter.cpp
qversitwriter_p.cpp
qvcard21writer.cpp
qvcard30writer.cpp
qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(65) : error C2872: '<lambda0>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(65): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda0>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactrelationship.h(58): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda0>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(65) : error C2872: '<lambda0>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(65): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda0>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactrelationship.h(58): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda0>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(66) : error C2872: '<lambda1>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(66): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda1>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactrelationship.h(59): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda1>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(66) : error C2872: '<lambda1>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(66): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda1>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactrelationship.h(59): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda1>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(67) : error C2872: '<lambda2>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(67): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda2>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactrelationship.h(60): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda2>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(67) : error C2872: '<lambda2>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(67): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda2>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactrelationship.h(60): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda2>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(68) : error C2872: '<lambda3>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(68): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda3>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactrelationship.h(61): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda3>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(68) : error C2872: '<lambda3>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(68): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda3>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactrelationship.h(61): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda3>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(69) : error C2872: '<lambda4>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(69): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda4>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactrelationship.h(62): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda4>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(69) : error C2872: '<lambda4>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(69): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda4>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactrelationship.h(62): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda4>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(70) : error C2872: '<lambda5>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(70): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda5>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactrelationship.h(63): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda5>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(70) : error C2872: '<lambda5>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(70): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda5>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactrelationship.h(63): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda5>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(71) : error C2872: '<lambda6>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(71): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda6>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactmanager.h(77): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda6>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(71) : error C2872: '<lambda6>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(71): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda6>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactmanager.h(77): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda6>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(72) : error C2872: '<lambda7>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(72): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda7>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactmanager.h(78): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda7>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(72) : error C2872: '<lambda7>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(72): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda7>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactmanager.h(78): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda7>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(73) : error C2872: '<lambda8>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(73): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda8>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactmanager.h(79): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda8>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(73) : error C2872: '<lambda8>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(73): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda8>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactmanager.h(79): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda8>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(74) : error C2872: '<lambda9>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(74): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda9>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactmanager.h(80): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda9>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(74) : error C2872: '<lambda9>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(74): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda9>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactmanager.h(80): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda9>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(75) : error C2872: '<lambda10>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(75): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda10>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactaction.h(94): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda10>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(75) : error C2872: '<lambda10>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(75): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda10>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactaction.h(94): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda10>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(76) : error C2872: '<lambda11>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(76): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda11>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactaction.h(95): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda11>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(76) : error C2872: '<lambda11>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(76): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda11>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactaction.h(95): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda11>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(77) : error C2872: '<lambda12>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(77): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda12>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactaction.h(96): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda12>'
.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(77) : error C2872: '<lambda12>': simbolo ambiguo
        potrebbe essere '.\qvcardrestorehandler_p.cpp(77): `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda12>'
        o 'c:\qt\qt5\qtbase\include\qtcontacts\../../../qtpim/src/contacts/qcontactaction.h(96): QtContacts::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda12>'
qversitcontactexporter.cpp
qversitcontactexporter_p.cpp
qversitcontactimporter.cpp
qversitcontactimporter_p.cpp
qversitresourcehandler.cpp
qversitcontacthandler.cpp
qversitcontactpluginloader_p.cpp
qversitutils.cpp
Generazione del codice in corso...
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : codice restituito '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\nmake.EXE"' : codice restituito '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : codice restituito '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : codice restituito '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : codice restituito '0x2'
Stop.
```

Can someone gently help me out? I've no clue whatsover!

I understeand the meaning of C2872 but I can't really believe that compiling a well known library as Qt throws it, nonetheless I have any clue on how eventually fixing this error in this specific case.

Comment: In most cases, `nmake clean` is a bad idea. Build Qt in a separate build folder, and to clean delete the entire folder. `nmake clean` will fail in many real-life scenarios, and there's nothing you can do about that. So don't use it.

Comment: Right, from now on I'll do a clean compilation. I'm going to download the package again from git. Thank you for pointing out that.

Comment: From git? Why? Get the official release `.zip`, otherwise you might run into trouble.

Comment: As a workaround, since it seems that versit fails to build for Qt Mobility, perhaps you can disable the building of the mobility module and retry.

Comment: @KubaOber I've read the opposite on the net. I do not remember exactly where, but it was written that the .zip sources are not a good idea, use git instead.

Comment: Context is everything. Someone said it in a particular context. Does your situation fit that other person's context? Were they talking **specifically** about Qt 5.5? The only time it'd make sense is if there were some changes done in Qt 5.5 branch after the last official release. It's easy to check if that's true, and if you could benefit from such changes. Qt's branches are usually closed after the final release in a given version, so I'm skeptical but haven't looked at the logs.

Comment: @KubaOber Right, thank you for the info about Qt Mobility. I'll try ASAP and let you know

Comment: @KubaOber Excuse me, can you gently tell me how to not compile Qt Mobility? -skip ???